# How to fix design Android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, tablet, smartphone

This is the XML, but for smartphone and Android it is a different design.
This is for the grid layout and the button in there.

This is the display for tablet:

[image]

And this for smartphone:

[image]

I want for all two user interfaces the full table

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:columnCount="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnWin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="4"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="2"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="3"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="4"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="5"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="6"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="7"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="8"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="9"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="10"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="11"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="12"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="13"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="14"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="15"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_columnSpan="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowSpan="1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

I don't understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple - height - 0dp:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
```